# Make a multiline plot from .CSV file in matplotlib

Tags: csv, matplotlib, pandas

I've been trying for weeks to plot 3 sets of (x, y) data on the same plot from a .CSV file, and I'm getting nowhere. My data was originally an Excel file which I have converted to a .CSV file and have used `pandas` to read it into IPython as per the following code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd
# define data location
df = read_csv(Location)
df[['LimMag1.3', 'ExpTime1.3', 'LimMag2.0', 'ExpTime2.0', 'LimMag2.5','ExpTime2.5']][:7]
```

My data is in the following format:

```
Type    mag1    time1   mag2    time2   mag3    time3

M0      8.87    41.11   8.41    41.11   8.16    65.78;

...

M6     13.95  4392.03  14.41 10395.13  14.66 25988.32
```

I'm trying to plot `time1` vs `mag1`, `time2` vs `mag2` and `time3` vs `mag3`, all on the same plot, but instead I get plots of `time..` vs `Type`, eg. for the code:

```
df['ExpTime1.3'].plot()
```

I get `'ExpTime1.3'` (y-axis) plotted against `M0` to `M6` (x-axis), when what I want is `'ExpTime1.3'` vs `'LimMag1.3'`, with x-labels `M0` - `M6`.

1. How do I get `'ExpTime..'` vs `'LimMag..'` plots, with all 3 sets of data on the same plot?
2. How do I get the `M0` - `M6` labels on the x-axis for the `'LimMag..'` values (also on the x-axis)?

Since trying askewchan's solutions, which did not return any plots for reasons unknown, I've found that I can get a plot of `ExpTime`vs `LimMag`using `df['ExpTime1.3'].plot(),`if I change the dataframe index (df.index) to the values of the x axis (LimMag1.3). However, this appears to mean that I have to convert each desired x-axis to the dataframe index by manually inputing all the values of the desired x-axis to make it the data index. I have an awful lot of data, and this method is just too slow, and I can only plot one set of data at a time, when I need to plot all 3 series for each dataset on the one graph. Is there a way around this problem? Or can someone offer a reason, and a solution, as to why I I got no plots whatsoever with the solutions offered by askewchan?\

In response to nordev, I have tried the first version again, bu no plots are produced, not even an empty figure. Each time I put in one of the `ax.plot`commands, I do get an output of the type:
 `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb5187b8>]`, but when I enter the command `plt.show()`nothing happens.
When I enter `plt.show()`after the loop in askewchan's second solution, I get an error back saying `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'show'`

I have done a bit more fiddling with my original code and can now get a plot of `ExpTime1.3`vs `LimMag1.3` with the code `df['ExpTime1.3'][:7].plot()`,by making the index the same as the x axis (LimMag1.3), but I can't get the other two sets of data on the same plot. I would appreciate any further suggestions you may have. I'm using ipython 0.11.0 via Anaconda 1.5.0 (64bit) and spyder on Windows 7 (64bit), python version is 2.7.4.

Comment: Just a thought; having `M0` - `M6` as labels on the x-axis would have no real meaning in this situation, as there are *three different* `LimMag..`-values for every `M..`-label, meaning that every label would have to be placed three different places on the axis. This will ultimately look very confusing rather than informative.

Comment: What is `plt` defined as?  It shouldn't be a `'function' object`  Are you familiar with using matplotlib and pyplot?

Comment: Hi askewchan, in answer to your question, I'm totally unfamiliar with matplotlib, pylab, python; in fact I've never done any sort of programming or used anything other than excel - hence the struggle..

Comment: @user2324693 Try looking here to get started with plotting: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Hi nordev, the solution with the log x-axis is probably the best, minus the end labels, as they're not correct, ie M0 is not the lowest valued spectral class. However, when I try to run it, I get an error message with respect to the range as 'expecting integer, but got float'. The data are decimals, but I don't know how to fix this so it will expect float, as I don't understand your code.

Comment: After loading your .csv as a `DataFrame` to the variable `df`, type `df` in your console, copy the output, and paste it in your wuestion above, so we can see if your `DataFrame` is correctly formatted (with M0-M6 being the index, not a separate column).

Comment: Also, write `df.columns` in the console, copy the output and paste in your question above.

Answer (score 12):

If I have understood you correctly, both from this question as well as your [previous one on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259345/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-matplotlib-with-multiple-x-and-y-axis-from-excel-data), the following should be basic solutions you could customize to your needs.

## Several subplots:

Note that this solution will output as many subplots as there are Spectral classes (M0, M1, ...) vertically on the same figure. If you wish to *save* the plot of each Spectral class in a separate figure, the code needs some modifications.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Here you put your code to read the CSV-file into a DataFrame df

plt.figure(figsize=(7,5)) # Set the size of your figure, customize for more subplots

for i in range(len(df)):
    xs = np.array(df[df.columns[0::2]])[i] # Use values from odd numbered columns as x-values
    ys = np.array(df[df.columns[1::2]])[i] # Use values from even numbered columns as y-values
    plt.subplot(len(df), 1, i+1)
    plt.plot(xs, ys, marker='o') # Plot circle markers with a line connecting the points
    for j in range(len(xs)):
        plt.annotate(df.columns[0::2][j][-3:] + '"', # Annotate every plotted point with last three characters of the column-label
                     xy = (xs[j],ys[j]),
                     xytext = (0, 5),
                     textcoords = 'offset points',
                     va = 'bottom',
                     ha = 'center',
                     clip_on = True)
    plt.title('Spectral class ' + df.index[i])
    plt.xlabel('Limiting Magnitude')
    plt.ylabel('Exposure Time')
    plt.grid(alpha=0.4)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

## All in same Axes, grouped by rows (M0, M1, ...)

Here is another solution to get all the different Spectral classes plotted in the same Axes with a legend identifying the different classes. The `plt.yscale('log')` is optional, but seeing as how the values span such a great range, it is recommended.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Here you put your code to read the CSV-file into a DataFrame df

for i in range(len(df)):
    xs = np.array(df[df.columns[0::2]])[i] # Use values from odd numbered columns as x-values
    ys = np.array(df[df.columns[1::2]])[i] # Use values from even numbered columns as y-values
    plt.plot(xs, ys, marker='o', label=df.index[i])
    for j in range(len(xs)):
        plt.annotate(df.columns[0::2][j][-3:] + '"', # Annotate every plotted point with last three characters of the column-label
                     xy = (xs[j],ys[j]),
                     xytext = (0, 6),
                     textcoords = 'offset points',
                     va = 'bottom',
                     ha = 'center',
                     rotation = 90,
                     clip_on = True)

plt.title('Spectral classes')
plt.xlabel('Limiting Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Exposure Time')

plt.grid(alpha=0.4)    
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(loc='best', title='Spectral classes')
plt.show()
```

[image]

## All in same Axes, grouped by columns (1.3", 2.0", 2.5")

A third solution is as shown below, where the data are grouped by the series (columns 1.3", 2.0", 2.5") rather than by the Spectral class (M0, M1, ...). This example is very similar to 
@askewchan's solution. One difference is that the y-axis here is a logarithmic axis, making the lines pretty much parallel.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Here you put your code to read the CSV-file into a DataFrame df

xs = np.array(df[df.columns[0::2]]) # Use values from odd numbered columns as x-values
ys = np.array(df[df.columns[1::2]]) # Use values from even numbered columns as y-values

for i in range(df.shape[1]/2): 
    plt.plot(xs[:,i], ys[:,i], marker='o', label=df.columns[0::2][i][-3:]+'"') 
    for j in range(len(xs[:,i])):
        plt.annotate(df.index[j], # Annotate every plotted point with its Spectral class
                     xy = (xs[:,i][j],ys[:,i][j]),
                     xytext = (0, -6),
                     textcoords = 'offset points',
                     va = 'top',
                     ha = 'center',
                     clip_on = True)

plt.title('Spectral classes')
plt.xlabel('Limiting Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Exposure Time')

plt.grid(alpha=0.4)    
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(loc='best', title='Series')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi nordev, I've just seen the above, thanks, I'll give it a go. I was hoping to be able to have them all on one plot, as I have 6 similar plots to do, all with 3 individual series (1.3", 2.0", and 2.5"). It's going to be an awful of of graphs if I have to do each spectral class independently! My first attempt was in Excel, it sort of did what I want, but only in a 3D plot, and it wasn'r very informative - hence the switch to matplotlib...

Comment: Hi nordev, thanks so much for all your hard work, it's really appreciated :) Hopefully I'll be able to work through this and get some useful graphs - very much a beginner here, up until two weeks ago I'd never done any type of programming before; talk about being thrown in at the deep end! lol :)

Comment: Hi nordev, as indicated above, this third option is the one I'd like to use, but without the M labels. Omitting the 'j' loop, I obtain a linear plot with the 'i' loop. However, when I run 'plt.title', I lose my plot and am left with an empty box. Running the rest of the code results in the error message:  C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py:4601: UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. ", and a nicely formatted grid with no data in it, despite having data in a linear plot after the 'i' loop ran.

Comment: Another question: How do I limit the number of rows to be plotted? I only want to go from M0 - M6. The full data as displayed after the 'i' loop goes to M9.

Comment: Re the comment re ending up with no data in my graph, I think the problem may have something to do with the (label=df.columns[0::2][i][-3]+'"') code, as I don't get the 'no labeled objects found' error if I omit it, but I still end up with no data once I input the title and x,y labels, or change the y axis to log. I have no idea what the problem might be, however, or how to fix it.

Comment: @user2324693 As when it comes to your plot getting "erased": The above code has to be _saved as a script_, and then run, as this code makes use of state-machine interface rather than the object-oriented interface. To limit the plotting to only include M0 - M6, change `plt.plot(xs[:,i], ys[:,i]...)` to `plt.plot(xs[0:6,i], ys[0:6,i]...)`.

Comment: I have played around a bit and managed to get your third solution to work, nordev. I altered 'd.shape[1]/2' to 'd.shape[1]', which solved the issue with the data types. I also discovered that the code works properly in a python console, but not in ipython. The command 'plt.show()' seems to be redundant; the graph appears and updates without issuing that command. Now all I have to figure out is how to restrict my data to the first 7 rows, and edit the text to display subscripts.

Comment: @user2324693 You should **really** read my comments to you! Altering `df.shape[1]/2` to `df.shape[1]` makes the range go from 0 to 5 rather than from 0 to 2, which is not intended for the above code; in fact it would raise an `IndexError`. Also, the above code should be **saved as a script**, not typed line by line in the IPython interpreter, as the above code uses the state-machine interface. When doing this, the command `plt.show()` is _not redundant_.

Comment: Hi nordev, thanks for telling me how to limit the data range; I've been trying all sorts of variations on your code, and looking for instructions in the numpy manual, but couldn't make it work. In the end, I simply cut those rows from my data.

Comment: Hi again nordev, I **do** read your comments. I had no idea what 'df.shape[1]/2' did, but when I ran the script (having saved it), I got the error 'was expecting an integer, and got a float'. When I changed it to 'df.shape[1], I didn't get that error, so I assumed the '/2' meant integer. I don't understand what you mean by 'range 0-5, or range 0-2'. I have just now run your code again in an ipython console from the script I saved, and once again,  a linear plot appears in the console window after the i-loop, but the data disappears once I run any of the subsequent code. ipython must have a bug

Comment: Re the Index Error with 'df.shape[1]': I do get an error 'index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3'. I don't know what this means, but it **seems** to not be causing any issues, as the rest of the code runs OK, and the resulting plot **looks** fine in the python console. If I change to 'df.shape[1]/2', I get the 'was expecting an integer, and got a float' error, and I get no data in the graph when I run the rest of your script. I get no data in the final graph in the ipython console, no matter which form of 'df.shape' I use.

Comment: @user2324693 The two points plotted in my example are from the data included in your question, so don't blame me if they are wrong. If you are using Python 3, you should specify integer division with `range(df.shape[1]//2)` (the `//` is the operator for integer division), as range only accepts integers. `/2` means divide by 2. Copy the code to a textfile and save it with the `.py` extension (e.g. `plot_spectral.py`), then run it (meaning you should **not** type _any_ code explicity in the console, as I suspect you are doing). What you are explaining is user-error, it's not a bug in IPython.

Comment: "Blame you"? where did that come from? Please don't yell at me, I'm just trying to understand what you've done, and why I'm still having problems. The code is in a .py file, I'm not typing into the console, and I'm using Python 2.7. The pandas docs say 'df.shape' gives the axis dimensions of the object, but there's no further info given, so I don't know why 'df.shape[1]/2' is being used. If 'range' only uses integers, this may explain why I've been getting the 'was expecting an integer, and got a float' error. My data is float64 - I'm sure I've told you that - and it needs to stay as float 64.

Comment: I've discovered that removing the 'i' loop and using the code 'plt.plot(xs[0:7], ys[0:7], label=df.columns[0::2][-3:]+'"')' solves the data type issues, but causes my legend to display incorrectly. Instead of getting the 3 line legend: '1.3', '2.0', '2.5', I get three lines of: 'Index([LimMag1.3", LimMag2.0", LimMag2.5"], dtype=object)' - interesting as " is not in any of my column headings. How do I get my original legend labels back?

Comment: I think I've finally solved the remaining problems, at least in an ordinary python console: Using the code from nordev's third solution, but omitting the 'i' loop, and substituting 'plt.plot(xs[0:7], ys[0:7])', and  'leg = plt.legend(('1.3','2.0', '2.5'),loc='best', title='Seeing (asec)') for the legend, returns a correctly formatted graph with no errors when ruin from a saved .py file in a python console. I still get no data in the graph when running this code from the same file in the ipython console, though, as before.

Comment: It seems you have a poorly formatted `DataFrame`. Read my comment under your OP.

Comment: Re 'poorly formatted DataFrame'; perhaps, but the data table looks OK when I run the command 'df.head()', so if there's something wrong, I don't know what it is. There's no missing data, no null columns or rows. 'df.dtypes' shows 6 correctly labelled float 64 columns, dtype 'object'.

Comment: **Please update** your question to include the contents of the .csv file (formatted **exactly** as the original .csv file, i.e. _not just the same content_!), as well as your approach to load this into a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @user2324693 Have you figured out how to achieve what you want? In particular, to load the data _correctly_ into a `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 3):

You can call `pyplot.plot(time, mag)` three different times in the same figure.  It would be wise to give a label to them.  Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(df['LimMag1.3'], df['ExpTime1.3'], label="1.3")
ax.plot(df['LimMag2.0'], df['ExpTime2.0'], label="2.0")
ax.plot(df['LimMag2.5'], df['ExpTime2.5'], label="2.5")
plt.show()
```

If you want to loop it, this would work:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for x,y in [['LimMag1.3', 'ExpTime1.3'],['LimMag2.0', 'ExpTime2.0'], ['LimMag2.5','ExpTime2.5']]:
    ax.plot(df[x], df[y], label=y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi askewchan, Thanks very much for the help, but there still seems to be a problem. I've run both of the codes you've provided, and even though no errors are being returned, no plots are being displayed. Is there a line of code missing, ie is there some code that should come between the ax.plot commands and the plt.show() commands? I get the distinct impression that ipython is waiting for some other input, but I have zero idea of what that might be..

Comment: @user2324693 Given that your DataFrame `df` is formatted correctly, then @askewchan's code should be working perfectly. At least I have no problem creating the plots from his code (pandas 0.11.0 & matplotlib 1.2.1).

Comment: @askewchan Your plots are "reversed" in the sense that `'ExpTime..'` should be on the y-axis, and `'LimMag..'` on the x-axis.

Comment: @user2324693 I'm not sure what would cause that.  As nordev seems to be able to get it to work, I don't know how to reproduce the problem (I don't have pandas).

Comment: Thanks @nordev, I am used to time being on the x-axis :P

Comment: Hi askewchan, that's OK, thanks for trying. I'm using pandas because I have very limited programming skills and I don't understand a lot of the code or how to use it. Pandas had good tutorials which I could follow, I just don't seem to be able to work out how to graph the columns I want. Pandas graphs against whatever the index is; so if I'm going to use that, it looks like I'll have to split my data sets into three separate files, so I can set the x axis to the corresponding y axis. I'd be happy to use numpy arrays, but I don't know how to write the code to access my data or plot my graphs.

Comment: @user2324693 The problem isn't pandas vs numpy (though numpy would work fine), but rather your plotting.  You should try making a very simple plot using matplotlib to see if that's the issue: `from matplotlib import pyplot`; `pyplot.plot([1,2,3,2,3])`; `pyplot.show()`

Comment: OK, that works. I think it may be the 'plt', instead of 'plot' that's causing the issue.

Comment: Hi askewchan and nordev, I've updated my version of ipython to 0.11.0 and have re-run both of askewchan's scripts. Still no errors, still no plots produced. If the problem is my dataframe, I don't know what's wrong with it. I've followed the pandas tutes on loading excel files, and have even converted them to .csv and ordinary text files, and I still don't get any plots. I have absolutely no idea why I don't get plots when you do. Perhaps you could show me exactly what you do to get my data into matplotlib, and then I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: I seem to have sorted out the dataframe issues, but I'm still having problems with the graph. I still get no output from askewchan's solutions, despite no errors being returned, and the code from nordev's third solution only seems to work to the end of the 'i' loop. Please see the comments following your third solution, nordev, for further explanation of the problem I'm having. I'm desperate for a solution to this; I'm out of time!

Comment: @user2324693 It's still not clear to me where the `plt()` error came from. Have you resolved that?  I think you'll need to post more code or data so that we can try to help more.

Comment: Hi askewchan, I've been using the code as per nordev's solution 3, below, but I didn't realize that 'range' requires integers. My data is float 64, so perhaps this is the source of the problem;  nordev may have thought my data was in integer format.

Comment: If you need to use floats, try using `np.arange` instead of `range`.