# Plot a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a data frame like this:

```
ReviewDate_month,ProductId,Reviewer
01,185,185
02,155,155
03,130,130
04,111,111
05,110,110
06,98,98
07,101,92
08,71,71
09,73,73
10,76,76
11,105,105
12,189,189
```

I want to plot it, ReviewDate_Month in X, Product ID and Reviewer in Y ideally. But I will start with 1 line either Product ID or Reviewer.
so i tried:

```
df_no_monthlycount.plot.line
```

Got below error msg:

```
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Assign2/Main.py", line 59, in <module>
01                      185       185
02                      155       155
03                      130       130
04                      111       111
05                      110       110
06                       98        98
07                      101        92
08                       71        71
09                       73        73
10                       76        76
    df_no_monthlycount.plot.line
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'line'
11                      105       105
12                      189       189

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also tried this:

```
df_no_monthlycount.plot(x=df_helful_monthlymean['ReviewDate_month'],y=df_helful_monthlymean['ProductId'],style='o')
```

Error msg like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Assign2/Main.py", line 52, in <module>
    df_no_monthlycount.plot(x=df_helful_monthlymean['ReviewDate_month'],y=df_helful_monthlymean['ProductId'],style='o')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1084, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2851, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3838)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3718)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12294)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12245)
KeyError: 'ReviewDate_month'
```

Comment: You are calling the plot method on a pandas dataframe. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568964/make-a-multiline-plot-from-csv-file-in-matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `plot` as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

print(df)

df.plot(x ='ReviewDate_month',y=['ProductId', 'Reviewer'] ,kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Will give you:

[image]

Comment: In fact, if i save the file to csv, and read csv back to a dataframe, your code works. However, my dataframe actually coming from a groupby "df_monthlycount = df_full[['ProductId','Reviewer','ReviewDate_month']].groupby(['ReviewDate_month']).count()" the plot doesn't work well with that, error msg as mentioned in my option2, any idea?

Comment: `df_monthlycount` is a dataframe. You should be able to do `df_montlycount.plot(x ='ReviewDate_month',y=['ProductId', 'Reviewer'] ,kind='line')` That gives an error as well?

Comment: You can check for your self, do `type(df_monthlycount)`

Comment: Yes. <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  One thing i notice is the month column was str, after save to CSV, it changed to numeric.

Comment: Did it work then, just doing `df_montlycount.plot(x ='ReviewDate_month',y=['ProductId', 'Reviewer'] ,kind='line')`?

Comment: no, it didn't, error msg same as I described in the 2nd part of my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93846/discussion-between-leb-and-jasmine).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot `ReviewDate_Month` in `X`, `Product ID` and `Reviewer` in `Y`, you can do it this way:

```
df_no_monthlycount.plot(x='ReviewDate_Month', y=['Product ID', 'Reviewer'])
```

Comment: maybe my question is a bit misleading. best is i can plot 2 lines, but the problem i am having now is i cannot even plot one line. I tried the my own 2nd way, i got those key error msg.

Comment: @Jasmine the code in my answer will `plot` 2 lines for you: `Product ID` and `Reviewer`

Comment: it will throw me the same error msg with what I use -  df_no_monthlycount.plot(x=df_helful_monthlymean['ReviewDate_month'],y=df_helful_monthlymean['ProductId'],style='o')