# Make a multiline stacked plot from .CSV file in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a multiline stacked plot from `.csv` file in matplotlib.

My `.csv` looks like this:

```
date    person 1    person 2    person 3
3/1/18  45.0        34.0        91.0
3/2/18  88.0        87.0        84.0
3/3/18  56.0        98.0        65.0
3/4/18  34.0        34.0        53.0
3/5/18  56.0        60.0        56.0
```

This should be simple but I can't get the slicing correct. Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df.head()

df.plot(xlim=(0, 10)

plt.title('Test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I don't want them to be stacked on the same chart. I'd like them to be stacked together like in this link: http://www.k-wave.org/documentation/stackedPlot.php

Would anyone be able to help?

I read through this: [Make a multiline plot from .CSV file in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568964/make-a-multiline-plot-from-csv-file-in-matplotlib) but not a lot of it is making sense to me because of how this person wanted to plot it. Mine seems more simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

In principle the desired plot can be achieved as follows.

- Normalize the dataframe to the range between 0 and 1,
- Shift each column by one more unit
- plot the dataframe

Complete example:

```
u ="""date    person 1    person 2    person 3
3/1/18  45.0        34.0        91.0
3/2/18  88.0        87.0        84.0
3/3/18  56.0        98.0        65.0
3/4/18  34.0        34.0        53.0
3/5/18  56.0        60.0        56.0"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y")
df = df.set_index("date")

# normalize
df /= df.values.max()
# shift colums
df += np.arange(len(df.columns))

ax = df.plot()
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.columns)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note how the plot is pretty hard to read. So as an alternative one could plot 3 individual plots, such that the data scales are preserved, using `subplots=True`:

```
u ="""date    person 1    person 2    person 3
3/1/18  45.0        34.0        91.0
3/2/18  88.0        87.0        84.0
3/3/18  56.0        98.0        65.0
3/4/18  34.0        34.0        53.0
3/5/18  56.0        60.0        56.0"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y")
df = df.set_index("date")

ax = df.plot(subplots=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help! I ran into few issues but figured out I needed to format that data like you did. Which worked! I also figured out to use `ax = df.plot(figsize(10,20), subplots=True)` to change the figure size. And this `ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)` to adjust the legend size! Thank you for all your help! I need to understand normalizing the dataframe more . I don’t understand what you mean by range between 0 and 1, so I plan to google and see what comes up!